# How to remove secondary UI component in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order, uicomponent, export

I want to remove export component from order toolbar page in Magento 2 admin.

I have already created an custom export component in my module but I want to remove default one.

See screenshot.[image]

Here is my code in "**sales_order_grid.xml**" in following folder

```
 app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/ui_component

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <container name="listing_top">
            <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToCsv</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mui/export/gridToXml</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="mom" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">mom</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MOM</item>
                                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mom/export/gridToMom</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </exportButton>
        </container>
    </listing>
```

My question is how to remove default one or override that in my module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
 <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
```

to

```
<exportButton name="export_button" class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
```

The value of argument "name" should be the same as the mentioned in sales_order_grid uiCompoment of exportButton tag.